# Mac - Displaying a modal window on tap of Print button in Print Dialog Extension

Tags: macos, driver, printers, printdialog

Is it possible to perform a custom action when the user taps the Print button? For example, can I display an Authentication dialog box before printing?

I am a newbie in Mac Printer Development. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PDE, I intercepted the print action in the following method:

`- (void)shouldPrint`

I displayed an NSWindow modally before returning YES or NO in that method.
(The execution of "shouldPrint" method is stopped when NSWindow is modally displayed.)